# Guidance with "It has been sufficiently updated from the source"

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501616/752842) with this comment:

> He copied the content from stackoverflow.com/a/1069509/752842, that
>   was suggested by dkozl on the question's comments

But it was *declined* with the message:

> It has been sufficiently updated from the source.

I also tried marking [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499407/how-to-display-a-bitmap-in-a-wpf-image) as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap). But that aged away.

To me is rather clear that the OP looked at the link provided by **dkozl**, that solved his issue and not knowing what else to do he just copied his code, that was a slight modification from the other answer's code.
The changes he did are negligible, he basically just surrounded the other code with a method and changed the format from `bmp` to `png`. I don't know, however, if it is asking too much to post something like that for moderator attention.

We could argue whether or not both questions are duplicate (although for me they seem to be), but I think is rather clear the OP got the code from the other answer. What do you do in cases like this? Did I flagged everything wrong? Why?

Comment: Attribution would have been nice. But other than that... you flag to get a moderator to do something. What should the moderator do in this case? There is no plagiarism here, its just a dude self-answering what worked for him which just happened to be the code from an existing answer almost verbatim.

Comment: @Gimby - To be honest, I didn't think of it as plagiarism, I mean not so seriously. I just saw something was wrong, and I wasn't sure what was the best way to go. Following Cody's advice it seems that marking it as a duplicate is the way to go, and a comment to the OP, which I didn't do because that post was bit old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your flags were *both* reasonable. Don't stop flagging when you see something wrong!

In this particular case, I agree with you about the questions being duplicates. We are literally overflowing with flags on questions suggesting closure, and they just don't all get reviewed before they age away. So that doesn't necessarily mean that people disagreed this was a duplicate. I went ahead and marked it as a duplicate, so [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

As far as the suspected code plagiarism, this is a tricky issue. Let me preface this by saying that I detest plagiarism, call it out often, and am a huge stickler for attribution. And also that I don't know what I would have done in this case, were I the moderator who handled that flag. But I cannot say that the moderator was incorrect in how (s)he chose to respond.

The two code snippets *are* very similar, but there's no real way to *prove* that Gerret copied the code from Pawel's answer. With a library, there are only a limited number of ways to do the same task. Pawel didn't invent something novel here, and Gerret could certainly have arrived at the same solution independently.

Since it is not a cut-and-dried issue of plagiarism, it would be wildly inappropriate to delete Gerret's answer outright. Beyond that, he clearly did make a couple of modifications to the code, tweaking it for his purposes, and that is perfectly acceptable. There are only two reasonable options as I see it:

1. Leave a comment on Gerret's answer, asking him if he adapted this code from what Pawel gave in his answer. The comment would remind him of the rules about attribution and *gently* suggest that he give credit where credit is due. This is appealing in theory, but probably not workable in practice, given that the answer is several years old now. If you want to do it, though, don't let me stop you.
2. Edit attribution directly into Gerret's answer. I was very tempted to do this, but backed off at the last minute for the above reasons—neither you nor I can actually *prove* that Gerret copied the code from Pawel's answer, and so to make a heavy-handed edit like that one would be putting words in his mouth.

Again, I'll reiterate that this is not a straightforward case. You were right to wonder, but ultimately I don't think it is a problem worth worrying about. Please don't stop flagging things that bristle your spidey-senses when you see them, though! There are plenty of cases of out-and-out plagiarism on Stack Overflow, and those deserve all of the flags they get. In my experience (and I have a fair amount of it), the moderators respond to these cases with swift and appropriate justice, so be reassured that your concerns are not falling upon deaf ears.

Comment: I actually understand better now, the comment saying it was updated sufficiently from the source was what threw me off. I believe the OP probably wasn't acquainted with how things are done in SO and that is why he did what he did. I really appreciate your insights, i do see a lot of duplicates that age away, I have to wait until I can post them again :P. In this case I realized something was wrong but I wasn't sure what to do.