# Editing question to provide attribution

Tags: discussion

I came across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627632/984830) today which was an *exact* copy of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897412/984830), even down to the comments included in the code.

The other answer was to another question - which had been marked as the duplicate for the new question. I edited the answer to provide attribution, but of course the plagiarist immediately rolled it back.

Now before I get into an edit war. **Was I right to do so?** I've always thought so because of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251390/984830)

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, explain the situation.

Comment: Thanks ;) and as to my question. Is it ok to edit someone elses anser for the express purpose of adding attribution?

Comment: It has happened to me too: [Original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036440/2664437) -  [Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29486677/2664437)

Comment: Haha I see they also didnt even remove "@Dave Wood pointed out" ...  careless

Comment: Actually ive flagged a few questions by the Rahul linked by EridB today... all of his top answers are plagiarized. will that lead to a ban?

Comment: @NickCardoso - The user EridB points out was warned about this at the time it was first discovered back in December. We just didn't see the rest of the plagiarized answers beyond the ones we cleaned up. Unless I'm missing something, I think they've stopped this since they were warned.

Comment: @BradLarson yes it seems like he gave up answering at all now he has to write the answers >.< No, you've probably not missed anything, the ones I flagged were all from '15, they were just easily recognisable because of the unchanged text and comments

Comment: @BradLarson considering I edited and flagged several of the questions, It's not far fetched to imagine he might go on an emotion-fueled hate-downvote spree seeing as his account is still active. Is there a way for SO to notice / prevent that? Because I'm pretty sure theres nothing I can do about it

Comment: @NickCardoso - If you are the subject of revenge downvotes at any point over the next week or so, just flag and let us know. We can track it back to the source, and if it is in retaliation for this they will be taking a significant vacation from the site. I've personally been the subject of multiple instances of serial downvoting after removing plagiarized content, and that did not end well for the people involved. Also why it can be easier to just flag specific instances of plagiarism and let moderators act on them.

Comment: Seems like the answer is gone... with my rep < 10k I cannot see it,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were right to do so, but the kind of people who post plagiarized content often have no apparent concept of why this is wrong. Either that or they know it is wrong and have a chronic lying disorder.

Either way, us regular users haven't the necessary tools to deal with the problem. The worst thing that could happen would be for you to get into an edit war with the fellow. Just flag the answer for moderator attention, use the "other" button to explain that the answer has been plagiarized without attribution from <give link to original>, and he has already rolled back one attempt to edit in attribution.

Answer (score 8):

You should not be editing attribution into a post like that.  Copying an answer like that isn't appropriate, even if you link back to the original it's still plagiarism and it's still not appropriate.  Flag the post for a moderator to delete.

Comment: At this point that's probably not possible because the new user who asked the question has selected it as the correct answer. Can a moderator delete a selected answer?

Comment: @NickCardoso Yes, a moderator can delete any answer.

Comment: @NickCardoso Moderators can delete anything. Accepted or not. In these kinds of cases usually moderators delete the answers that are plagiarised.

Comment: @NickCardoso - Also, if someone has accepted an answer that was plagiarized from another question, it can be a great indication of a duplicate. I'll often delete the answer and mark the duplicate at the same time.

Comment: ...for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35337410/19679

Comment: In addition to flagging, remember to down vote!

Comment: @Lundin The answer needs to be deleted.  It's score is irrelevant, as it's not going to exist shortly after you flag it.  It's certainly okay to downvote, but it's not all that important.

Comment: "even if you link back to the original it's still plagiarism" -- Huh? It may still be inappropriate but it obviously isn't plagiarism if the attribution is there.

Comment: @hvd No.  Copying the entirety of someone else's work and re-distributing it with no added value, even if attributed, is still plagiarism.

Comment: @Servy Check a dictionary, or if you think a dictionary is not appropriate, come up with a better definition. But you're saying that if I am asking someone to copy something for me (like, say, a file hosting service), and that person complies, that person is a plagiarist. That, quite frankly, is a load of BS.

Comment: @hvd The context here is intellectual property, not products.  That is where plagiarism is relevant.  Going around duplicating a bunch of other's SO answers, even if you also link back to them, is plagiarizing them.

Comment: As far as a definition, you'll find most sources providing a definition will state that there is no a clear, unambiguous definition.  However, it's a frequent occurrence to see something like, "Providing proper citations, but fails to change the structure and wording of the borrowed ideas enough." or "Relying too heavily on other people’s work. Fails to bring original thought into the text." both of which are quotes from the Wikipedia page on the subject.

Comment: @Servy For the examples from Wikipedia, if I'm writing a paper that presents several insights, citing another paper as the source for existing ones while claiming that the new ones are my own when my paper doesn't have any new ones, that's tricking people into thinking some of the existing ones are mine even if I never clearly made that claim. That's not the case we're talking about. And there's no relevant difference between code in an SO answer and that released on a file host in tarball form. Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for SO's definition. It matches what I wrote.

Comment: @hvd What are you talking about?  That SO page completely supports my position, "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own."

Comment: @Servy It *defines* plagiarism as "posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own" right at the start, and doesn't claim or try to claim that all the things on that page are to be avoided because it's plagiarism. Some of the things to avoid are simply because they're illegal, because they're copyright infringement.

Comment: @hvd So you're saying only the first sentence of the page matters, and that we should ignore all of the rest of it because it doesn't support your position?

Comment: @Servy No, I'm not saying that. You're reading something into that page which it doesn't say. I'm saying to focus on what it does say. If you insist that attributing content properly can still be plagiarism, can I suggest you flag [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251583) as plagiarism and see what happens?

Answer (score 5):

Answers directly and without modifications plagiarised from another question on Stackoverflow should be deleted, even when they recieve attribution. Why?

Consider these two scenarios:

1. The copied answer does adress the question properly.

In this case, the question is a duplicate of the question that had the original answer, and the answerer should have flagged/voted to close as dupe instead of copying an answer

2. The copied answer does not adress the question properly.

In this case the answer is tosh for that question and deserves to be deleted anyways.

Comment: In the case at hand here, the person who plagiarized (because attribution was missing) had in fact adapted the answer (i.e modified it). So your premise "without modification" does not apply to the case being discussed.

Comment: @Louis replacing a string literal with a variable is not a significant change that warrants re-posting an existing answer from a duplicate question.

Comment: Not to mention that it is in fact the OP that sets up the premise of there being no modifications, as that is what an *exact* copy would imply as quoted directly from the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster "Without modifications" (the answer's premise) is not the same as "with modifications that are not significant" (my understanding of your criterion).

Comment: @Louis alright, you got me there. This answer, however, as Gimby indicates, answers the question's claim here that it was unmodified. [This question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism/251390#251390) handles modified copypasta. It is very typical though that the poster of the answer we're talking about here is unable to come up with an original answer when the code in question is like two relevant statements, apart from some variable initialization.

Comment: @CodeCaster True, and Magisch cannot look at the answer now that it has been deleted, and see that the OP's "exact copy" is incorrect.

Comment: For reference, here is a very recent example where it went the other way: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317492/guidance-with-it-has-been-sufficiently-updated-from-the-source

Comment: As an addition, if the respective questions are closed as duplicates of each other (or should be), a mod might be induced to merge them if at least one answer from the dupe adds something not yet on the master.